# How to get regex quantifier to work as expected?

Tags: python, regex

Currently I am trying to match an entire email with specific prefixes (the stuff that comes before the `@`) and I can't seem to figure it out. Right now I have a regex that, with the online tools I used, should work but in python it only matches the first part of the email

```
import re
test = "info@c.com test2@c.com support@c.com"
print(re.findall('(info|contact|support|help|sales)+@\w+\.{1}\w+', test))
```

Returns

```
['info', 'support']
```

Expected Result

```
['info@c.com', 'support@c.com']
```

Comment: Just make your alternation a non-capturing group: `(?:info|contact|support|help|sales)+@\w+\.{1}\w+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findall`

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result.

So let's change your regex like this:

```
import re
test = "info@c.com test2@c.com support@c.com"
print(re.findall('((?:info|contact|support|help|sales)+@\w+\.{1}\w+)', test))
```

output:

```
['info@c.com', 'support@c.com']
```